# Jquery mobile application architecture

Tags: facebook, wcf, jquery-mobile, wcf-data-services

I have a few questions, I want to write a web app using JQUERY Mobile, WCF or ASP.NET WEB API as service & FACEBOOK AUTHENTICATION.

I want certain pieces of my app to be only visible to logged in users. How can I make sure that a User is redirected to the Login page when she directly types the address of that page in her mobile browser, instead of showing the page contents (with JQUERY or JAVASCRIPT)?

Answer (score 2):

Use a session based token for service communication between app and website.
For requests without valid session redirect to login page.

Comment: can you please elaborate it by writing one or two lines of code.